# https display main website in magento

Tags: .htaccess, magento

I have multi store website in magento for which i have created multiple websites and their stores, and i want to open one of the website using https, but using that it redirects to main website.

My configuration->web settings are

```
Add Store Code to Urls  Yes

Auto-redirect to Base URL  Yes(302 Found)
```

My main website is www.perkhotel.com and subwebsite is www.http://www.manhattantowerfl.com but when itry to open https://www.manhattantowerfl.com it is showing content of www.perkhotel.com.

My .htaccess settings are

```
SetEnvIf Host www\.perkhotel\.com MAGE_RUN_CODE=base
SetEnvIf Host www\.perkhotel\.com MAGE_RUN_TYPE=website
SetEnvIf Host ^perkhotel\.com MAGE_RUN_CODE=base
SetEnvIf Host ^perkhotel\.com MAGE_RUN_TYPE=website


SetEnvIf Host www\.manhattantowerfl\.com MAGE_RUN_CODE=cognijet
SetEnvIf Host www\.manhattantowerfl\.com MAGE_RUN_TYPE=website
SetEnvIf Host ^manhattantowerfl\.com MAGE_RUN_CODE=cognijet
SetEnvIf Host ^manhattantowerfl\.com MAGE_RUN_TYPE=website
```

Answer (score 0):

Nested in the Magento admin panel are further settings for declaring the use of secure URLs. Have look in the 'Design' and 'Web' tabs to ensure SSL is enabled and configured correctly.